# Can I override links in /usr/bin/ by .zshrc?

Tags: linux, bash, python, arch-linux, zsh

I have `/usr/bin/python` mapped to `/usr/bin/python3.7`, but I prefer to use `python3.6` instead. So I recreated links manually, but each time I update my system with `pacman -Syu` I have them overwritten by system defaults again.

What is the best practice to handle this? Should I add `alias python=/usr/bin/python3.6` (which makes non-cli apps use wrong python anyway) or some other option to make my system run `python3.6` by default when I run `python` from anywhere?

Comment: Is there an [`alternatives` command](https://tech.lanesnotes.com/2008/03/using-alternatives-in-linux-to-use.html) in arch-linux?

Comment: @xenoid looks like I can use this for managing multiple php versions?

Comment: You can use this for plenty of things. When your repo has several versions for the same package, each version  comes with its setup for `alternatives`.

Answer (score 1):

If programs only require `python` and do not specify its full path, you can create another directory with the correct symlink and put it in the front of your $PATH.

For example:

```
$ mkdir ~/bin
$ ln -s /usr/bin/python3.6 ~/bin/python
$ export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
$ type python
python is /home/xxx/bin/python
$ python --version
Python 3.6.x
```

If programs specifically require `/usr/bin/python`, there's nothing you can do about it without root privileges. (And you **shouldn't,** as programs distributed with Arch often expect the same Python that is distributed with Arch – it's only safe to use an older version with *your own* programs.)

However, root can change this <del>either temporarily using mount namespaces,</del> or permanently by just moving the file away. To change it permanently (and risk breaking official packages):

1. In the general [options] section of /etc/pacman.conf, add `NoUpgrade = usr/bin/python`.
2. Use `ln -s` to change the actual /usr/bin/python symlink in whatever way you want. After a Python upgrade, the new link will be extracted to /usr/bin/python.pacnew and won't reset your changes.

Comment: Thank you for idea with symlink folder! Sounds awesome